# How to use importValue and join in Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a stack which depends on a value which is exported in a different stack (value is `supertest`)

I try to use it as below

```
OriginAccessIdentity: !Join [ "", [ "origin-access-identity/cloudfront/", !ImportValue: !Sub "supertest-${Environment}" ] ]
```

But I got a syntax error while this works (hardcoding the supertest value)

```
OriginAccessIdentity: !Join [ "", [ "origin-access-identity/cloudfront/", "lol-dev" ] ]
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I believe that syntax is not valid.

Try this:

```
OriginAccessIdentity:
  Fn::Join:
    - ""
    - - "origin-access-identity/cloudfront/"
      - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "supertest-${Environment}"
```

Here is another example where i use it similarly: https://github.com/faermanj/Sitting-Ducks/blob/master/cfn-beanstalk-env.yml

Comment: This works, now I also need to put this inside a cloudformation if: !If [check, if true then the Fn::Join: - "", .. (the parth above); , if false then just "ok"]. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Great, try using each statement/argument in separate line and always validate the YAML. The cloudformation lint is quite useful: https://github.com/awslabs/cfn-python-lint